# Derive Feynman rules for interacting Proca theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, path-integral, feynman-diagrams, interactions

Is there a smooth way to derive the Feynman rule for the interaction term

$$\mathcal{L}_{int}=gA_{\mu}A^{\mu}A_{\nu}A^{\nu}?$$

$A_{\mu}$ denotes a massive vector field.

Comment: When in doubt, one can always write the generating functional and then take appropriate functional derivatives, setting background fields to 0 at the end. What do you mean by smooth?

Comment: To be honest, I have never learnt how to derive interaction Feynman rules for general fields....In the lecture we just have discussed scalar fields so far, where one often can directly see the corresponding vertex.....Is it possible that you can show me the procedure with the generating functional for this specific interaction? Would be very helpfull....I have a good background with path integral methods, so I really just need to see how to derive the Feynman rule...